# Server to server data migration

Tags: redhat, migration

I want to migrate my old server (Redhat Enterprise) data to a new server (Rackspace hosting) without downloading the files.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please, give some more information to avoid guessing

Comment: You should include at least the source and destination OS and how much data you have.

Comment: Without moving a physical server from location A to location B, how would you do this without downloading/transferring files, unless you're well versed in manipulating wormholes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

log into old and rsync to new server

Answer (score 2):

Dump the file system of the server and send it over, then restore the files you need?

```
/sbin/dump -0uan -f - / | gzip -2 | ssh -c blowfish user@backupserver.example.com dd of=/backup/server-full-backup-`date '+%d-%B-%Y'`.dump.gz

restore -i
```

Answer (score 0):

Log into the new one and ftp the data from the old one across?

Answer (score 0):

tar the files up, scp them across, and untar them